# Looking for software that can transfer PDF files and print them automatically (and then move them to a processed folder)

Tags: pdf, printing, data-transfer

I'm running a webshop that is hosted online. Shipping labels for orders are currently exported once a day in a CSV file. I import them, and then print them to my local printer.

We want to automate this process. I have a programmer who has already managed to create the pdf files for the shipping labels.

Now I am looking for software that can transfer (ftp, ssh, http, ...) these files from the (remote) webshop to our server, and print them automatically to our label printer, and then (if print was successful) move these pdf files in a 'processed' folder.

Do you know of software that can do this?

Preferably Windows based.

Thanks.

Comment: I would end up writing my own PowerShell script to do this...

Answer (score 0):

The software [watchdirectory.net](https://watchdirectory.net/) can do this.

It has a 30 day evaluation period and cost $79 US for s standard version